# Facebook messenger 'get started' button

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

Im currently making a chatbot on the messenger platform. 
I want to implement the get started button. I have the button appearing when the user first initiates conversation with the bot. The problem is i don't know what to do from there. The docs don't explain very well how to respond appropriately when the button is clicked. The following curl command is used to implement the button.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
 "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
 "thread_state":"new_thread",
 "call_to_actions":[
 {
   "payload": {
     "message" : {
        "text": "Get started"
       }
     }
   }
  ]  
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settingsaccess_token=XXXX"
```

Any help on how to actually use the get start button would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your bot running already?
If so you have nothing to do, FB manages everything on his side for you.
Once the 'get started' button is clicked, it will call you program exactly like it does when a user uses a button (handled through 'postbacks').

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. If I run the curl command in my terminal, with my pages access token, it activates the getting started button?

Comment: Yes, it is that simple

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I'm facing similar issues to yours and since there is no other answered questions regarding this topic in Stack Overflow and this remains unanswered, these are some things that might fix your issue.

First of all, you should check your request because, [as described in the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/get-started-button), the endpoint where you need to target your curl post request is `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN` (mind the question mark).

Secondly, it is also worth checking that the `payload` attribute is expecting a **string**, and not an object as you are sending here. Sending an stringified JSON should work too.

Also, you probably need to make sure that you have correctly set up your Messenger endpoint and events in the Facebook Developer Panel, specifically the event `messaging_postbacks`.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to pull off the payload off the request.body

It will contain the post-back defined in the curl request
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/postback

Messenger will post to your webhook address everything that happens on the page subscription , like incoming messages or the postback from the get started button

Have a look at the example from Facebook documentation 
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/messenger-bot?path=bot.js:1:0

```
// Message processing
app.post('/webhook', function (req, res) {
..
}
```

Check the receivedPostback function in the example I linked your get started action will be in the postback variable.